# Как перенести изменения одного git репозитория в другой?

Tags: git, bitbucket

Есть локальный git репозиторий, в нем несколько веток, появилась необходимость заморозить разработку одной отдельной ветки, и удалить её из основного репозитория.

Каким образом можно вынести эту ветку в другой репозиторий сохранив при этом всю историю этой ветки в новом репозитории?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. подключаете второе хранилище:

   ```
   $ git remote add repo2 url-хранилища
   ```
2. отправляете туда ветку:

   ```
   $ git push repo2 имя-ветки
   ```
3. если необходимо, удаляете ветку в основном хранилище (если оно называется у вас не `origin`, внесите корректировку):

   ```
   $ git push origin :имя-ветки
   ```

   обратите внимание на двоеточие перед именем ветки. это часть синтаксиса.

   впрочем, нынче можно и чуть более наглядный синтаксис использовать:

   ```
   $ git push origin --delete имя-ветки
   ```